# Multidimensional array argument type inference

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array, tuples, type-inference

When passing a generic multidimensional array T[][] (or rest params of T[]), it looks like typescript expects the type of the arrays following the first array to be a superset of the first array types.

```
function abc<T>(values: T[][]): T[] {
    return values[0];
}

abc([[1], ['string'], [2], [3]]) // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Why is that? and can I get it to infer the type as (number | string)[][]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I figured out how to make this work.

If you specify the multidimensional array as a generic type it works as expected:

```
function abc<T, TMultiArray extends T[][]>(arr: TMultiArray): T[] {
    // Pseudo logic that returns any of the values
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
```

This doesn't give an error anymore and by default infers the return type as unknown[]

```
abc([[1], ['string']])
```

And this gives an error as expected

```
const y: number[] = abc([[2], ['string']]) // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not give it a hint that you want it to be a union type?

```
abc<string | number>([[1], ['string'], [2], [3]])
```

In your case it gives you the error because TS assumes that you want `T` to be a single type, not a union type.

Imagine if TS always went along with whatever types you put into the array and just expanded the type to match it. You'd lose the whole benefit of type checking and could possibly end up with a `string | number | boolean | etc` union type, which is essentially equivalent to `any` and is unlikely to be what you intended.